# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 50, 30, 3) but got array with shape (1, 3, 50, 30)

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to convert my Deep learning network written in Matlab to Python via Keras libraries. Network's task is to recognize specific note in given image, and return single character corresponding to specific sound name ('from 'a' to 'h')

Code in Matlab:

```
digitDatasetPath = fullfile('zbior_uczacy');
imds = imageDatastore(digitDatasetPath, ...
'IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource','foldernames');

labelCount = countEachLabel(imds)

img = readimage(imds,1);
size(img)

numTrainFiles = 1200;
[imdsTrain,imdsValidation] = splitEachLabel(imds,numTrainFiles,'randomize');

layers = [
imageInputLayer([50 30 1])

convolution2dLayer(6,12,'Padding',1)
reluLayer

maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

convolution2dLayer(6,24,'Padding',1)
reluLayer

maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

convolution2dLayer(6,48,'Padding',1)
reluLayer

fullyConnectedLayer(7)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer];


options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
        'LearnRateSchedule', 'piecewise', ...
        'LearnRateDropFactor', 0.3, ... 
        'LearnRateDropPeriod', 5, ... 
        'MaxEpochs', 50, ... 
        'MiniBatchSize', 300);

net = trainNetwork(imdsTrain,layers,options);

YPred = classify(net,imdsValidation);
YValidation = imdsValidation.Labels;

accuracy = sum(YPred == YValidation)/numel(YValidation)
```

Code has been already tested, working fine.
Now I'm trying to convert this code into Keras code. Full code here:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Input
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import image

print("\n")
print("\n")
trained_weights = []
trained_bias = []

trained_weights = np.loadtxt('Weights.csv', delimiter=';')
trained_bias = np.loadtxt('Bias.csv', delimiter=';')
network_weights = np.array([[trained_weights]])
network_outputs = np.array([['a','c','d','e','f','g','h']])

# Load test image
img = load_img('note_a.png')
note = image.img_to_array(img)
note = np.expand_dims(note, axis=0)

# Model architecture
model = Sequential()

# Layer 1
model.add(Convolution2D(12, (6, 6), input_shape=(50, 30, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Layer 2
model.add(Convolution2D(24, (6, 6), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Layer 3
model.add(Convolution2D(48, (6, 6), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(48))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

model.set_weights([network_weights])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#model.fit((note,network_outputs), batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(note, network_outputs)
```

To avoid all the learning, I just exported weights of learned matlab network to .csv file, then imported them to my network. So goal of this code is to just recognize the given image, then return the character. No learning here.

That code returns following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Train_Keras.py", line 51, in <module>
score = model.evaluate(note, network_outputs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 989, in evaluate
sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1723, in evaluate
batch_size=batch_size)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1414, in _standardize_user_data
exception_prefix='input')
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 153, in _standardize_input_data
str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 50, 30, 3) but got array with shape (1, 3, 50, 30)
```

My question is, am I doing image to array conversion correctly? And how I'm supposed to add empty row to array? Found somewhere that if I will add to first convolutional layer batch size:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(12, (6, 6), batch_size=1, input_shape=(50, 30, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Then error change to: 'Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (1, 50, 30, 3)', but I'm not sure if adding batch_size wouldn't change network activity.

Also, I found somewhere that reshaping image the exact way network wants it to may help:

```
note = np.reshape(note, [1, 50, 30, 3])
```

However that returns following error. To be honest, I totally don't understand that one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Train_Keras.py", line 52, in <module>
score = model.evaluate(note, network_outputs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 989, in evaluate
sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1729, in evaluate
self._make_test_function()
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1012, in _make_test_function
**self._function_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1233, in function
return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1219, in __init__
**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 317, in function
output_keys=output_keys)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
output_keys=output_keys)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1839, in orig_function
name=name)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1519, in __init__
optimizer_profile = optimizer(fgraph)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 108, in __call__
return self.optimize(fgraph)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 97, in optimize
ret = self.apply(fgraph, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 251, in apply
sub_prof = optimizer.optimize(fgraph)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 93, in optimize
self.add_requirements(fgraph)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 1488, in add_requirements
fgraph.attach_feature(ShapeFeature())
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\fg.py", line 546, in attach_feature
attach(self)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 1305, in on_attach
self.on_import(fgraph, node, reason='on_attach')
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 1368, in on_import
self.set_shape(r, s)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 1157, in set_shape
shape_vars.append(self.unpack(s[i], r))
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\opt.py", line 1079, in unpack
raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: There is a negative shape in the graph!
Backtrace when that variable is created:

File "Train_Keras.py", line 30, in <module>
model.add(Convolution2D(12, (6, 6), input_shape=(50, 30, 3), activation='relu'))
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 464, in add
layer(x)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 603, in __call__
output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 164, in call
dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
File "C:\Users\Karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1913, in conv2d
filter_dilation=dilation_rate)
```

Would be grateful for any tips how to solve this problem. 
Thank You!

Comment: Try setting the `data_format` to `"channels_last"` in the call to `img_to_array` (or in your `keras.json`.  The shape of `note[1:]` needs to match the input shape of the first conv layer.

Comment: Then I get following error:
    File "Train_Keras.py", line 42, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(48))
    ...
    ValueError: ('The specified size contains a dimension with value <= 0', (-48, 48))

Comment: Something is wrong with the layer shapes of your model. You can debug by printing `model._layers()[-1]._keras_shape`... my guess is that the issue is that your original model pads the convolutions, but the keras one doesn't (`Conv2D` layers aren't padded by default). You can either use the `padding` flag of the `Conv2D` layers or add in ZeroPadding2D layers https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d, I think?

Comment: You're right. Because network didn't have paddings, size of the layers was hugely decreased, which eventually led to size lesser than zero. Adding padding helped me in this case.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yay! Glad it worked out